# Different behavior for versions 4.0 & 4.1 when searching hex values in file using awk

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk

I am trying to find a string of hexadecimal values in a file like this:

```
$ awk '/\x00\x01\x02\x03/ {exit 1;}' myfile.bin
$ echo $?
```

I am sure the file contains such values, as I can see them in VI (in hexdump mode)

```
00000000: ad33 0215 0001 0203 e1fa 8f76 1941 cd07  ....
......
```

If I do that using `awk` on a machine with version 4.1.3 (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS), it works (returns 1). With `awk` version 4.0.3 (on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS machine), it returns 0.

The file used in both cases is identical (actually mounted on a NAS to both machines). I also checked `awk`'s changelog, but to no avail.

Comment: How did you get that gawk? My 14.04.5 test machine (with no change to repos) has 1:4.0.1+dfsg-2.1ubuntu2 which works correctly for your case (exit status 1) and [launchpad agrees with that version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/gawk)

Comment: I just installed the 4.0.1 version from launchpad on this machine, but still I get the same result.

Comment: That's bizarre. My /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk has sha1sum c53d7c1c580979561333c345210276e51b4d517a if you want to check, although I'd be astonished if the official repo doesn't get the file(s) correct. ldd doesn't show many libraries other than libc, which I don't _think_ would affect this, although it shows libdl which might be used to load anything else. I'm not sure what else I can usefully check, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible with your real data, but I was able to reproduce your error and create a replacement code that works more reliably.  It should also be faster since it avoids the regular expression.

First, let's create a reproducible test:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c%c%c%c", 0, 1, 2, 3}' > myfile.bin
$ hexdump -C myfile.bin
00000000  00 01 02 03                                       |....|
00000004
```

Okay, so now we can test this out:

```
[gawk 4.0.2]$ gawk --version |awk NR==1
GNU Awk 4.0.2
[gawk 4.0.2]$ gawk '/\x00\x01\x02\x03/ {exit 1}' myfile.bin; echo $?
0
```

And on another system:

```
[gawk 4.1.4]$ gawk --version |awk NR==1
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
[gawk 4.1.4]$ gawk '/\x00\x01\x02\x03/ {exit 1}' myfile.bin; echo $?
1
```

Reproduced.

Let's use `index()` instead of a regular expression:

```
[gawk 4.0.2]$ gawk 'index($0, "\x00\x01\x02\x03") { exit 1 }' myfile.bin; echo $?
1
```

```
[gawk 4.1.4]$ gawk 'index($0, "\x00\x01\x02\x03") { exit 1 }' myfile.bin; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I don't have the machine on which I encountered the issue anymore, but you have my upvote :)